# PHP variable not equal but returning true

Tags: php, wordpress

So this seems like it should be easy but I have no idea why it isn't working. I am a weekend code warrior so there is a good chance that there is something obvious I am missing. The problem is I am doing a simple if statement to check if a variable is equal to a number or 'string', and when it is clearly not equal it is still running the if statement.

```
$user = ca_get_user(get_current_user_id());
    $role = $user->role;
        if ($role == '2'):
            print_r ($role);
        endif;
```

This returns this

1

Well, because the role is defined as 1. So I think unless my logic has been warped for a long time this shouldn't happen. I have done a is_numeric check on $role and that came back as false. I've also tried it as number just for good measure. Am I missing something that would have this return as true? (it actually runs against any comparison. And doesn't run against any comparison if I set it to !=)

Variable was set to database with this.

```
<select name="user_company_type" required>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Company Type*</option>
                                <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['user_company_type']) && $_POST['user_company_type'] == '1') echo 'selected'; ?>>General Contractor</option>
                                <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['user_company_type']) && $_POST['user_company_type'] == '2') echo 'selected'; ?>>Architect</option>
                                <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['user_company_type']) && $_POST['user_company_type'] == '3') echo 'selected'; ?>>Owner/Developer/OPM</option>
                                <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['user_company_type']) && $_POST['user_company_type'] == '4') echo 'selected'; ?>>Sub-Contractor</option>
                                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['user_company_type']) && $_POST['user_company_type'] == '5') echo 'selected'; ?>>Building Consultant</option>
                            </select>
```

Comment: This is invalid code, sorry. What are the `?>` doing in there? And what is `role` meant to be in `$user>role`?

Comment: Saw that as soon as posted typed it wrong. Trying to figure out how to edit post now. Pretend that is not there and its valid code in general

Comment: Probably you want to check something like that: `if (2 === intval($role))`

Comment: Sorry, still not much better. The trailing `?>` makes no sense and `$user>role` is still strange...

Comment: OK, getting better now. But the issue probably is the comparision between whatever type `$user->role` actually is and the string `2`. Try to find out that type to compare more precisely and use `===` for type safe comparision instead of the sloppy `==` which often leads to annoying surprises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is what you want to express, provided `ca_get_user()` returns some sort of object with `role` being a property in there:

```
$user = ca_get_user(get_current_user_id());
$role = $user->role;
if (2 === intval($role)):
    print_r ($role);
endif;
```

A more classical implementation would be:

```
$user = ca_get_user(get_current_user_id());
$role = $user->role;
if (2 === intval($role)) {
    print_r ($role);
}
```

Not sure whether the `intval()` call is required, that depends in the class definition which I don't know. But it is *probably* safe to add it and it might prevent some surprises. You really should find out about the type of `$user->role` by either looking at the documentation or by dumping the user object once.

Comment: Neither solutions helped in this case, but I did a dump on the user as suggested it opens up a whole other can of worms. it showed [role] => 3 but the print_r ($role) returns 1 (which is what it should be actually). Thanks for help. I have some more investigation to do.